# http in angular 2.0 post

Tags: html, http, angular

How can I add my form data to my db using http, well I tried doing this but caught at an error, can someone do it.

My template

```
    <h1>Address Form</h1>

     <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">
Error messages per field and disabled save button until entire form is valid.
    </div>
          <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(myForm.value)" #myForm="ngForm">
    <div class="form-row">
    <div class="formHeading">First Name</div>
    <input type="text" id="firstName" ngControl="firstName">

   </div>

   <div class="form-row">
    <div class="formHeading">Street Address</div>
    <input type="text" id="firstName" ngControl="streetAddress">

   </div>

   <div class="form-row">
    <div class="formHeading">Zip Code</div>
    <input type="text" id="zip" ngControl="zip">

   </div>

   <div class="form-row">
    <button type="submit" >Save</button>
   </div>

</form>
```

My component

```
   import {Component} from '@angular/core';

   import {FormBuilder, Validators, ControlGroup, FORM_DIRECTIVES}  from '@angular/common';

 @Component({

    templateUrl: './components/address-form/address-form.html',
    directives: [FORM_DIRECTIVES],
}) 
 export class AddressForm {
 onSubmit(form:any):void {
  console.log(form);

}
   }
```

This is what I have done so far, can anyone suggest what I should do more since I am not able to see anything in db.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: ngFormModel expects a form. Please pass one in. Example: <form [ngFormModel]="myCoolForm">

Comment: Maybe try and remove the `ngFormModel` directive.

Comment: if i reomve how can i bind values fro form,is it possible?

Comment: What does `console.log(value);` spit out?

Comment: I have changed the [(ngFormModel)] to  (ngFormModel)  and i am getting the following error ------------TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of null

Comment: With `remove` I mean remove the whole thing, not just `remove the square brackets`.

Comment: with that removed i am getting error undefined post

Comment: which is from component

Comment: Are you able to see data in php? Do you get data at php side?

Comment: yes i do @micronyks and here i am trying to post data

Comment: Thats what i wanted to check. So its like you are having some trouble at server side and not at front end.

Comment: no micronyks i am fine with server end

Answer (score 1):

Change your `form` tag to this:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(myForm.controls)" #myForm="ngForm">
```

and in your `onSubmit()` method this should work:

```
onSubmit(form) {
    console.log(form.firstName);
    console.log(form.lastName);
    console.log(form.phone);

    // ...
}
```

Comment: igot  something like    *It looks like you're using the old forms module. This will be opt-in in the next RC, and
      will eventually be removed in favor of the new forms module. For more information, see:
      https://docs.google.com/document/u/1/d/1RIezQqE4aEhBRmArIAS1mRIZtWFf6JxN_7B4meyWK0Y/pub
    
bundle.js:13 undefined

Comment: Did you add the variable to the `onSubmit` method?

Comment: Well, you have now a field called zip, and no phone anymore. Do you understand what you program?

Comment: i am getting the firstname in my console

Comment: Great, then add your http post call back and try it out! :)

Comment: yes i will try nw rinukkusu,actually i just chnged the phone to zip just as a small change pls do not mind it

Comment: hi i am getting the error XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost/a2server/index.php/profile/addprofile. Request header field Content-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
EXCEPTION: Response with status: 200 Ok for URL: null

Comment: You have to activate CORS on your server side (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)

Comment: i am using my localapi

Comment: i put <?php header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');  there

Comment: Also add `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`